# DevTools shows empty elements tab and sources

Tags: angular, nativescript, nativescript-angular

No matter what DevTools I use (Chrome / Inspector) the elements tab is always blank, and at times the bundle.js / vendor.js files do not show in sources either.

I'm using the latest versions of TNS / Angular with Webpack, using the standard generated webpack config file.

I have tried both Chrome and Inspector. I've tried adding --env.sourceMap as well, but still nothing. Every error shows within bundle.js and vendor.js and I can't view elements.

This is happening on Mac (iOS builds).

Webpack Config file:

```js
const { join, relative, resolve, sep, dirname } = require("path");

const webpack = require("webpack");
const nsWebpack = require("nativescript-dev-webpack");
const nativescriptTarget = require("nativescript-dev-webpack/nativescript-target");
const { nsReplaceBootstrap } = require("nativescript-dev-webpack/transformers/ns-replace-bootstrap");
const { nsReplaceLazyLoader } = require("nativescript-dev-webpack/transformers/ns-replace-lazy-loader");
const { nsSupportHmrNg } = require("nativescript-dev-webpack/transformers/ns-support-hmr-ng");
const { getMainModulePath } = require("nativescript-dev-webpack/utils/ast-utils");
const CleanWebpackPlugin = require("clean-webpack-plugin");
const CopyWebpackPlugin = require("copy-webpack-plugin");
const { BundleAnalyzerPlugin } = require("webpack-bundle-analyzer");
const { NativeScriptWorkerPlugin } = require("nativescript-worker-loader/NativeScriptWorkerPlugin");
const TerserPlugin = require("terser-webpack-plugin");
const { getAngularCompilerPlugin } = require("nativescript-dev-webpack/plugins/NativeScriptAngularCompilerPlugin");
const hashSalt = Date.now().toString();

module.exports = env => {
    // Add your custom Activities, Services and other Android app components here.
    const appComponents = [
        "tns-core-modules/ui/frame",
        "tns-core-modules/ui/frame/activity",
    ];

    const platform = env && (env.android && "android" || env.ios && "ios");
    if (!platform) {
        throw new Error("You need to provide a target platform!");
    }

    const AngularCompilerPlugin = getAngularCompilerPlugin(platform);
    const projectRoot = __dirname;

    // Default destination inside platforms/<platform>/...
    const dist = resolve(projectRoot, nsWebpack.getAppPath(platform, projectRoot));
    const appResourcesPlatformDir = platform === "android" ? "Android" : "iOS";

    const {
        // The 'appPath' and 'appResourcesPath' values are fetched from
        // the nsconfig.json configuration file
        // when bundling with `tns run android|ios --bundle`.
        appPath = "src",
        appResourcesPath = "App_Resources",

        // You can provide the following flags when running 'tns run android|ios'
        aot, // --env.aot
        snapshot, // --env.snapshot
        uglify, // --env.uglify
        report, // --env.report
        sourceMap, // --env.sourceMap
        hiddenSourceMap, // --env.hiddenSourceMap
        hmr, // --env.hmr,
        unitTesting, // --env.unitTesting
    } = env;

    const isAnySourceMapEnabled = !!sourceMap || !!hiddenSourceMap;
    const externals = nsWebpack.getConvertedExternals(env.externals);
    const appFullPath = resolve(projectRoot, appPath);
    const appResourcesFullPath = resolve(projectRoot, appResourcesPath);
    const tsConfigName = "tsconfig.tns.json";
    const entryModule = `${nsWebpack.getEntryModule(appFullPath, platform)}.ts`;
    const entryPath = `.${sep}${entryModule}`;
    const entries = { bundle: entryPath };
    if (platform === "ios") {
        entries["tns_modules/tns-core-modules/inspector_modules"] = "inspector_modules.js";
    };

    const ngCompilerTransformers = [];
    const additionalLazyModuleResources = [];
    if (aot) {
        ngCompilerTransformers.push(nsReplaceBootstrap);
    }

    if (hmr) {
        ngCompilerTransformers.push(nsSupportHmrNg);
    }

    // when "@angular/core" is external, it's not included in the bundles. In this way, it will be used
    // directly from node_modules and the Angular modules loader won't be able to resolve the lazy routes
    // fixes https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-cli/issues/4024
    if (env.externals && env.externals.indexOf("@angular/core") > -1) {
        const appModuleRelativePath = getMainModulePath(resolve(appFullPath, entryModule), tsConfigName);
        if (appModuleRelativePath) {
            const appModuleFolderPath = dirname(resolve(appFullPath, appModuleRelativePath));
            // include the lazy loader inside app module
            ngCompilerTransformers.push(nsReplaceLazyLoader);
            // include the new lazy loader path in the allowed ones
            additionalLazyModuleResources.push(appModuleFolderPath);
        }
    }

    const ngCompilerPlugin = new AngularCompilerPlugin({
        hostReplacementPaths: nsWebpack.getResolver([platform, "tns"]),
        platformTransformers: ngCompilerTransformers.map(t => t(() => ngCompilerPlugin, resolve(appFullPath, entryModule), projectRoot)),
        mainPath: join(appFullPath, entryModule),
        tsConfigPath: join(__dirname, tsConfigName),
        skipCodeGeneration: !aot,
        sourceMap: !!isAnySourceMapEnabled,
        additionalLazyModuleResources: additionalLazyModuleResources
    });

    let sourceMapFilename = nsWebpack.getSourceMapFilename(hiddenSourceMap, __dirname, dist);

    const config = {
        mode: uglify ? "production" : "development",
        context: appFullPath,
        externals,
        watchOptions: {
            ignored: [
                appResourcesFullPath,
                // Don't watch hidden files
                "**/.*",
            ]
        },
        target: nativescriptTarget,
        entry: entries,
        output: {
            pathinfo: false,
            path: dist,
            sourceMapFilename,
            libraryTarget: "commonjs2",
            filename: "[name].js",
            globalObject: "global",
            hashSalt
        },
        resolve: {
            extensions: [".ts", ".js", ".scss", ".css"],
            // Resolve {N} system modules from tns-core-modules
            modules: [
                resolve(__dirname, "node_modules/tns-core-modules"),
                resolve(__dirname, "node_modules"),
                "node_modules/tns-core-modules",
                "node_modules",
            ],
            alias: {
                '~': appFullPath
            },
            symlinks: true
        },
        resolveLoader: {
            symlinks: false
        },
        node: {
            // Disable node shims that conflict with NativeScript
            "http": false,
            "timers": false,
            "setImmediate": false,
            "fs": "empty",
            "__dirname": false,
        },
        devtool: hiddenSourceMap ? "hidden-source-map" : (sourceMap ? "inline-source-map" : "none"),
        optimization: {
            runtimeChunk: "single",
            splitChunks: {
                cacheGroups: {
                    vendor: {
                        name: "vendor",
                        chunks: "all",
                        test: (module, chunks) => {
                            const moduleName = module.nameForCondition ? module.nameForCondition() : '';
                            return /[\\/]node_modules[\\/]/.test(moduleName) ||
                                appComponents.some(comp => comp === moduleName);
                        },
                        enforce: true,
                    },
                }
            },
            minimize: !!uglify,
            minimizer: [
                new TerserPlugin({
                    parallel: true,
                    cache: true,
                    sourceMap: isAnySourceMapEnabled,
                    terserOptions: {
                        output: {
                            comments: false,
                            semicolons: !isAnySourceMapEnabled
                        },
                        compress: {
                            // The Android SBG has problems parsing the output
                            // when these options are enabled
                            'collapse_vars': platform !== "android",
                            sequences: platform !== "android",
                        }
                    }
                })
            ],
        },
        module: {
            rules: [
                {
                    test: nsWebpack.getEntryPathRegExp(appFullPath, entryPath),
                    use: [
                        // Require all Android app components
                        platform === "android" && {
                            loader: "nativescript-dev-webpack/android-app-components-loader",
                            options: { modules: appComponents }
                        },

                        {
                            loader: "nativescript-dev-webpack/bundle-config-loader",
                            options: {
                                angular: true,
                                loadCss: !snapshot, // load the application css if in debug mode
                                unitTesting,
                                appFullPath,
                                projectRoot,
                            }
                        },
                    ].filter(loader => !!loader)
                },

                { test: /\.html$|\.xml$/, use: "raw-loader" },

                // tns-core-modules reads the app.css and its imports using css-loader
                {
                    test: /[\/|\\]app\.css$/,
                    use: [
                        "nativescript-dev-webpack/style-hot-loader",
                        { loader: "css-loader", options: { url: false } }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    test: /[\/|\\]app\.scss$/,
                    use: [
                        "nativescript-dev-webpack/style-hot-loader",
                        { loader: "css-loader", options: { url: false } },
                        "sass-loader"
                    ]
                },

                // Angular components reference css files and their imports using raw-loader
                { test: /\.css$/, exclude: /[\/|\\]app\.css$/, use: "raw-loader" },
                { test: /\.scss$/, exclude: /[\/|\\]app\.scss$/, use: ["raw-loader", "resolve-url-loader", "sass-loader"] },

                {
                    test: /(?:\.ngfactory\.js|\.ngstyle\.js|\.ts)$/,
                    use: [
                        "nativescript-dev-webpack/moduleid-compat-loader",
                        "nativescript-dev-webpack/lazy-ngmodule-hot-loader",
                        "@ngtools/webpack",
                    ]
                },

                // Mark files inside `@angular/core` as using SystemJS style dynamic imports.
                // Removing this will cause deprecation warnings to appear.
                {
                    test: /[\/\\]@angular[\/\\]core[\/\\].+\.js$/,
                    parser: { system: true },
                },
            ],
        },
        plugins: [
            // Define useful constants like TNS_WEBPACK
            new webpack.DefinePlugin({
                "global.TNS_WEBPACK": "true",
                "process": undefined,
            }),
            // Remove all files from the out dir.
            new CleanWebpackPlugin([`${dist}/**/*`]),
            // Copy assets to out dir. Add your own globs as needed.
            new CopyWebpackPlugin([
                { from: { glob: "fonts/**" } },
                { from: { glob: "**/*.jpg" } },
                { from: { glob: "**/*.png" } },
            ], { ignore: [`${relative(appPath, appResourcesFullPath)}/**`] }),
            // Generate a bundle starter script and activate it in package.json
            new nsWebpack.GenerateBundleStarterPlugin(
                // Don't include `runtime.js` when creating a snapshot. The plugin
                // configures the WebPack runtime to be generated inside the snapshot
                // module and no `runtime.js` module exist.
                (snapshot ? [] : ["./runtime"])
                    .concat([
                        "./vendor",
                        "./bundle",
                    ])
            ),
            // For instructions on how to set up workers with webpack
            // check out https://github.com/nativescript/worker-loader
            new NativeScriptWorkerPlugin(),
            ngCompilerPlugin,
            // Does IPC communication with the {N} CLI to notify events when running in watch mode.
            new nsWebpack.WatchStateLoggerPlugin(),
        ],
    };

    // Copy the native app resources to the out dir
    // only if doing a full build (tns run/build) and not previewing (tns preview)
    if (!externals || externals.length === 0) {
        config.plugins.push(new CopyWebpackPlugin([
            {
                from: `${appResourcesFullPath}/${appResourcesPlatformDir}`,
                to: `${dist}/App_Resources/${appResourcesPlatformDir}`,
                context: projectRoot
            },
        ]));
    }


    if (report) {
        // Generate report files for bundles content
        config.plugins.push(new BundleAnalyzerPlugin({
            analyzerMode: "static",
            openAnalyzer: false,
            generateStatsFile: true,
            reportFilename: resolve(projectRoot, "report", `report.html`),
            statsFilename: resolve(projectRoot, "report", `stats.json`),
        }));
    }

    if (snapshot) {
        config.plugins.push(new nsWebpack.NativeScriptSnapshotPlugin({
            chunk: "vendor",
            angular: true,
            requireModules: [
                "reflect-metadata",
                "@angular/platform-browser",
                "@angular/core",
                "@angular/common",
                "@angular/router",
                "nativescript-angular/platform-static",
                "nativescript-angular/router",
            ],
            projectRoot,
            webpackConfig: config,
        }));
    }

    if (hmr) {
        config.plugins.push(new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin());
    }

    return config;
};
```

Comment: is it happening on Mac or Windows?

Comment: Do you have a sample repository or a playground sample? I suppose its something specific in your app. I suggest you try with a new ng app (tns create newApp --ng).

Comment: @Narendra I am using Mac.

Comment: @DimitarTachev Unfortunately not, a new app works fine, but then I have a year+ of development that I have to copy over manually, which is a ridiculous amount of work just so I can debug.

Comment: @DavidHopson It could be caused by an old webpack plugin/config. If you don't have some custom webpack configurations, I suggest you try updating your webpack plugin and webpack.config file by using `npm i nativescript-dev-webpack@latest --save-dev` and `./node_modules/.bin/update-ns-webpack --configs`.

Comment: @DimitarTachev Hi. Updated my question to clarify, but I have updated both the configs and dependencies. I'll add my webpack config to the question too.

Comment: I'm on NS 5.4 and diff'ing your webpack config with mine, only yields a single change:
`platformTransformers: ngCompilerTransformers.map(t => t(() => ngCompilerPlugin, resolve(appFullPath, entryModule))),`
vs yours
`platformTransformers: ngCompilerTransformers.map(t => t(() => ngCompilerPlugin, resolve(appFullPath, entryModule), projectRoot)),`

Comment: What does your CLI output after starting an emulator from Android Studio when running
`tns debug android --device emulator-5554`
?

Comment: If you're on VSCode, you can also try to debug from there using
https://www.nativescript.org/nativescript-for-visual-studio-code